# What are the applications of Widest path problem?

Tags: algorithm, graph, path

I want to know some more applications of the widest path problem. [CLICK!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem)
It seems like something that can be used in a multitude of places, but I couldn't get anything constructive from searching on the internet.

Can someone please share as to where else this might be used? 
thanks in advance.
(what I searched for included uses in p2p networks and CDN, but I couldn't find exactly how it is used / the papers were too long for me to scout.)